# How come my divs are jumping around during a transition?

Tags: html, css

I have a bunch of rectangle `<div>` elements that I am using to display some companies. When you hover over the element, it displays an extra couple of boxes containing clickable links below the rectangle. When the user stops hovering, those boxes go away. The problem is, the UI is very jumpy if there are other boxes below this `:hovered` box.

I have set `margin-bottom: 60px`on the `<div>`. When the user hovers, a 40px expansion comes out below it. When this expansion comes out, I set `margin-bottom: 20px`. This works fine for going out, but when the the expansion goes in, it jumps.

*Makes more sense after viewing the Fiddle:*

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/50q74j9a/2/

I would like it to not jump around when the user stops hovering over a box. I know it has something to do with the transition, I just don't know how to fix it.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="catalog-item" data-categories="1">
        <div class="item-title">
            <img style="visibility: hidden" src="/Content/images/white_square_icon.gif" alt="menu-icon" />
            <div style="visibility: hidden" class="favorite-icon-inactive"></div>
        </div>  <a href="#" target="_blank">
            <img class="supplier-logo" src="http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/cswikia/images/d/d6/Steam_logo_2014.png/revision/latest?cb=20140910122059" alt="Steam Bakery logo" /></a>

        <div class="supplier-name">Steam Bakery</div>
        <div class="supplier-info"> <span><a href="#" target="_blank">Program Info</a></span>
    <span class="contact-info">Contact Info</span>

    </div>
</div>
```

**Partial CSS:**

```
.catalog-item {
    width: 150px;
    height: 175px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    /*margin-bottom: 20px;*/
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid #0E80B4;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;
    -moz-transition: height .4s;
    -webkit-transition: height .4s;
    -o-transition: height .4s;
    transition: height .4s;
    text-align: center;
}
.catalog-item:hover {
    height: 215px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because you are only setting the transition for the `height` but you are also changing the element's `margin` as well. Try this so they transition at the same time.

```
.catalog-item {
   width: 150px;
   height: 175px;
   margin-right: 20px;
   /*margin-bottom: 20px;*/
   margin-bottom: 60px;
   background-color: white;
   border: 1px solid #0E80B4;
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;
   -moz-transition: all .4s;
   -webkit-transition: all .4s;
   -o-transition: all .4s;
   transition: all .4s;
   text-align: center;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/imtheman/50q74j9a/5/)

Comment: The fast and the deleted :)

Comment: @OriDrori Quickest draw in the Stack. ;) Ok, not really, I just got lucky.

Comment: Cool. It is my first time using `transition` CSS property. Thanks for the fiddle!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing the container's height, you should add a negative margin-bottom to the sliding info box. It's less work for the browser than adjusting the height and position at the same time.

```
.catalog-item:hover .supplier-info {
    margin-bottom: -47px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aLabnvss/

Comment: This works, but I don't like the visual effect of the bottom of the div not moving when the extra content appears/disappears

Comment: I would also like to comment that this is faster than the "best answer" solution. On slower computers, the best answer solution can really bog down if there are a lot of entries on the page. This one is better for older PC's.

Answer (score 0):

add `min-height` for division

```
.catalog-item {min-height:215px;}
```